# Correct way of implementing a Model for a Dropdownlist .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, dropdownlistfor

I'm currently trying to implement a Dropdown List with what I would assume is hardcoded values. Basically what I want is to have a Dropdown List with a choice of three possible values.

I have a total of 4 controllers and views that will be using this dropdown. I've seen a lot of examples for MVC2 and MVC3 where people have hard coded their dropdowns in their views, and I personally don't prefer to go with a quick and "dirty" fix such as that.

I have a model containing the following.

```
public class Status
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    public Status(int statusId, string statusName)
    {
        id = statusId;
        status = statusName;
    }
}
```

The status should be able to have any of the 3 possible values:

```
Active
Inactive
Processing
```

I thought of creating the status' using this method I currently have in my status class:

```
    public static List<Status> getAllStatus()
    {
        List<Status> states = new List<Status>();
        states.Add(new Status(1, "Active"));
        states.Add(new Status(2, "Inactive"));
        states.Add(new Status(3, "Processing"));
        return states;
    }
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to use this model inside my Controllers alongside with how to pass it along to my views and was hoping someone in here would known how to do that?

## EDIT1:

I guess I forgot to mention that I will be storing the selected value as a string in my database and that I am using a view which doesn't have the model of my status class, but rather the model of object which I will be storing in my database (which might be the case of a vehicle object).

## EDIT2:

I have a model called Customer, which has some of the following values:

```
public int CustomerID { get; set }
public string Email { get; set }
public string Phone { get; set }
public Status Status { get; set; }
```

In my DB for my Customer model I have a string in which I wan to store the selected Status.

So basically I wan't to change the following to a dropdown with 3 options, `Inactive`, `Active` and `Processing`.

[image]

However I don't want to code this in my view as I will be needing it in 8 different views and copy pasting that is not very *sleek* code.

Comment: Is it an option to use an enum instead of a class that hold id+name? In that case you have EnumDropDownListFor

Comment: That could be done, but I don't know how to do with either. I know how to create an enum, but the problem is that I will be storing the selected value as a string in my database.

Comment: That's about your Controller, not about your View. Do you need it as string? Use .ToString() when you pass your ViewModel property to your Model property (or an attribute if it's not a valid identifier...)

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.status_id, new SelectList(getAllStatus(), "id", "status"))
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that I will be storing the selected value as a string in my database and that I am using a view which doesn't have the model of my status class, but rather the model of object which I will be storing in my database.

Comment: i think we can't do without class status because options came from database.

Comment: It doesn't. I want the values to be "hardcoded", and not be saved in the database, but I want to store the selected option as a string in my database for the object that I am saving.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.status_id, new List<SelectListItem>
                                        {
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "Active", Selected=true},
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "InActive"},
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "Processing"}
                                        })` try this but without database.

Comment: This pretty much is hardcoding it in the view which I explained in my question is not what I want. I will be needing this piece of code in a total of 8 views and just/copy pasting it in all of them is bad program design.

Answer (score 1):

To start you have a lot of vague questions. Be more specific if you can. If you don't know how MVC works that well I would recomment to follow some tutorials on it.

Model.cs (A ViewModel is preferred). You Should create a ViewModel which you passes to the View. Below is an example how to get a list of items.

```
    public int SelectedStatusId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusItems
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "- Select a status -" };
            StatusTypeEnum[] values = (StatusTypeEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusTypeEnum));

            foreach (StatusTypeEnum item in values)
            {
                if (item != StatusTypeEnum.Unknown)
                {
                    yield return new SelectListItem { Value = ((int)item).ToString(), Text = item.GetDescription() };
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

StatusTypeEnum.cs

```
  public enum StatusTypeEnum()
  {
      [Description("Active")] // For correct naming
      Active,
      Inactive,
      Processing
  }
```

View.cshtml

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedStatusId, Model.StatusItems)
```

EnumAttribute.cs (To read the Annotation Descriptions. And don't try to understand this. It's just magic. It gets the DataAnnotation of the enum types by reflection.)

```
  public static class EnumAttribute
  {        
    public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum value)
    {
        var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        if (fi != null)
        {
            var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                return attributes[0].Description;
            }
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to be more specific in my question. Please read my edit :P

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to save it as a string within your database as it sounds more like something static. So u should consider an Enum. To me more precise look to my previous answer and add those Model properties to a ViewModel.

```
      public class CustomerViewModel () {
            public int SelectedStatusId { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Status")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusItems
{
    get
    {
        yield return new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "- Select a status -" };
        StatusTypeEnum[] values = (StatusTypeEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusTypeEnum));

        foreach (StatusTypeEnum item in values)
        {
            if (item != StatusTypeEnum.Unknown)
            {
                yield return new SelectListItem { Value = ((int)item).ToString(), Text = item.GetDescription() };
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Pass this into your View through your controller:

```
   public class CustomerCOntroller(){
         public ActionResult Index(){
              CustomerViewModel viewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
              return View(viewModel);
         }       
  }
```

And you are done. If u are more working with a list which u need to build up add it to your viewModel object.

Greetings,

S..

Answer (score -1):

You could declare States as public propery in your class and use this to access it in your views:

```
  <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding States}"     
    IsTabStop="False"}"/>
```

Comment: thank you :)
How did you formatted it, so the code will appear?

Comment: This question is about ASP.NET MVC, not WPF. Please see the tags under the question. :)